# Getting dimensions of matrix from a list of matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I want to store a list of matrices. I do this by constructing matrices using matrix and concatenating it using list. Essentially, suppose I have:

```
A = matrix(1,2,2)
B = list(A,A)
```

Then how do I obtain the dimensions of A from B alone? I can obtain a matrix element using B[1], but cannot extract the dimensions. Please help.

Comment: `lapply(B, dim)`?  Or `dim(B[[1]])`?  Notice the double bracket notation

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot. I am a newbie to R and cannot understand these fancy expressions. Any quick starter guide you know? Thanks again for the quick answer.

Comment: Yeah, [this one](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html) is good.

Answer (score 1):

`dim(B[[1]])` will tell you the first matrix in list B has dimensions 2 by 2